oracle select * from tableA, is the column order returned is following column_id in tableA
For oracle, TableA, assume



column_name
Column_id




colA
1


colB
2


colC
3


col...
x




Then when run the sql:
select * from TableA, is the result must follow the column_id order, that is the result must be
colA,colB,colC,col...
and not
colB, col..., colA, colC
?

It is described in SELECT statement's documentation, which says

select_list
The select_list lets you specify the columns you want to retrieve from the database.
* (all-column wildcard)
Specify the all-column wildcard (asterisk) to select all columns, excluding pseudocolumns and INVISIBLE columns, from all tables, views, or materialized views listed in the FROM clause. The columns are returned in the order indicated by the COLUMN_ID column of the *_TAB_COLUMNS data dictionary view for the table, view, or materialized view.


I suspect that select * will return the columns in ID order, but I do not think it's guaranteed. You really should enumerate the column names specifically.

Not really (at least, not in Oracle).
